# Chart movement , scrolling and zooming smoothly with touches

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, tradingview-api

I make a chart in angular
Let chart = $(‘#chartContainer’).stockChartX(config)

and this chart have panels inside these panels event

PaneGestureEvent
mouseEvent.continue
timeSchale.scrollToPixel(offset.x)

but the scroll and movement and zooms of this chart not smooth , Is there any library I can install it in angular can make the movement , scrolling and zooming of the chart smoothly like this link
note (I need to make it smooth when I use phone touches , so maybe it not difference on pc )

Link : https://www.tradingview.com/script/qK7Ko9Ff-example-Event-Statistics/